# take value from color picker and transfer to data-pb-tint-colour using paintjs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple script here with a color picker built in I want to take the selected color and transfer it to the image as a tint with paintjs.  I have looked all over for ways to tranfer the color hex value to the data-pb-tint-colour but can't find anything.  Is there a way to do this?

## HTML:

```
<form name="colorForm">
   <p>Select Color
   <input name="colorpicker" type="color" onchange="newBackgroundColor(colorpicker.value);">
   </p>
   <p>
   Selected Color
   <input name="selectedcolor" type="text">
   <img src="/Layer2.png" class="filter-tint" data-pb-tint-opacity="0.5" data-pb-tint-colour="#F69023">
   </p>
</form>
```

### Java script and Jquery and PaintJS:

```
 <script language="javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="common.js"></script>
        <script src="paintbrush.js"></script>
      <script>
      function newBackgroundColor(color)
      {
        
         document.colorForm.selectedcolor.value = color;
         
      }
      </script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8emrzjoj/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in JQuery:

```
$('#colorpicker').on('input', function() { 
    var color= $("#colorpicker").val();
    $("#hexvalue").val(color); 
    $('#image').attr('data-pb-tint-colour', color);  
});
```

you'll need to give your color picker input field, the image, and the text input field ids. `colorpickerid` stands for the color picker's id, `hexvalue` for the input text field's id, and `image` for the image. No need for the `onchange` handler with this.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eeguctqg/)

Comment: This works great except I get confused on how to transfer the values to data-pb-tint-colour for applying of the color tint?

Comment: have tested this in my devbox since my external sources do not seem to be working and while the color tint does show on the image that is first set in the data-pb-tint-colour I can not get it to change to any other color how you have it setup.

Comment: Can anyone else help figure this out? I have spent hours trying to get it to work and it should work but it is not. I'm pulling my hair out lol.

Comment: Well, I know that the `data-pb-tint-colour` is being changed at least. You can create a new question about how to dynamically change the tint color in PaintJS.